2gen package version creation: Unable to find Apex action class that already exists
I have added some custom fields with xml files in an existing 2nd generation package and I'm trying to create a new version of it to test it in my scratch org (with sf package version create --package "Foobar" -c --installation-key-bypass), but it fails with:

admin:  Unable to find Apex action class referenced as 'AdminController'.

AdminController exists already from the previous  versions of this package, as do all the files that reference it (admin too, mentioned in the error). The new files I've added don't use or query this apex class at all, and are not interacting with the old files either. I've created other beta versions of this package the last few days without problem.
What is going wrong here? Should I be looking at something else to debug this?

Generally it is not a great idea to delete classes from packages, and this seems not to be your case with this class, so the issue is indeed elsewhere.
Another possible cause for the "unable to find class" issue is when the class fails to compile in your package creation deployment (when you create a package, Salesforce seems to run some sort of deployment-like process, so the errors are quite similar). In short: because the compilation fails for the class, the deployment fails because that class "was not found".
Try deploying your package's source to a new scratch org with these added changes, and see if your Apex class still compiles successfully. If possible, run the tests for it too.

Thank you this helped a lot! Turns out I had added some files in the .forceignore during development and I realised it when I was about to deploy the changes to a new scratch org as per your suggestion, haha I thought I was losing it. Thanks!
